# Is itinery/itinary an acceptable pronunciation of "itinerary"?

Tags: pronunciation

There are enough Google results with the misspelling above to suggest I'm not the only person who pronounces *itinerary* incorrectly.

So is this common or even acceptable to pronounce it in this way?

Excuse me if I'm way off the mark, but do the majority of people pronounce it differently from its spelling?

Comment: Nice 印章 !

Comment: I think it's just one of those words whose pronunciation has evolved due to careless rounding off of the word.  Like the word probably tends to be pronounced "probly."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/aɪˈtɪnərəri/  seems to be the correct pronunciation, but have a listen: http://www.forvo.com/word/itinerary/

at least two of them do  /aɪˈtɪnəri/

My personal opinion is to pronounce words the way the majority of respectable dictionaries and, for example news readers, would pronounce them. If I have been convinced that my pronunciation is incorrect (I try to speak and write British English) I will change it regardless of what a minority (or even a majority) would use.

Comment: The name for this sort of shortening is *haplology*, which is the shortening of a word that contains two similar syllables.

Comment: The preferred U.S. pronunciation is /aɪˈtɪnərˌɛri/, from which it is much less likely that a syllable will be dropped. I expect this will end up one of the words like military and laboratory, where the British pronunciation drops a syllable that the Americans don't.

Comment: As ever, we Brits lead the way in discarding redundant phonemes! I just wish we could apply the same **rigour** to orthography.

Comment: It's weird... I don't know if the people/voices on forvo.com change often, but the first 3 pronunciations currently for itinerary, seems to be something like: /tɪnərəri/. In other words, the leading "i" is omitted, leaving only: "tinerary". At first I thought it was an issue of how the voices were edited/played back (and that might be the actual case), but the remainder of the people/voiced clearly pronounce it with the leading "i". So I wonder if "tinerary" (or maybe even "tinery") is actually used as well.